# QT + CUDA setting qmake.pro file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt4, cuda

I'm trying to do a simple Qt + Cuda framework with an Helloworld.cu example. It is the simplest Qt ever. I'm trying to create the project file using a .pro file. My setup is windows 7, Qt 4.7.4 and Cuda toolkit + SDK (last version). Everything for Qt is working. What is not working is the Cuda part of the code, and that's probably because there is something missing in the .pro file...is there a simple paste/copy i could use for cuda in my .pro file? thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using CMake it supports both CUDA and Qt, and lot of other stuff :-)

Comment: Are you saying that it would be easier to use CMake for setting a Cuda + Qt project than QMake?

Comment: I would think so. http://developer.qt.nokia.com/quarterly/view/using_cmake_to_build_qt_projects and https://gforge.sci.utah.edu/gf/project/findcuda/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=%2F*checkout*%2Ftrunk%2FFindCuda.html easy peasy ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://cudaspace.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/qt-creator-cuda-linux/

You must adjust

```
# Path to cuda SDK install
CUDA_SDK = /pathto/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C (note i'm using a linux machine)
# Path to cuda toolkit install
CUDA_DIR = /usr/local/cuda

# libs - note than i'm using a x_86_64 machine
LIBS += -lcudart -lcutil_x86_64
```

with your CUDA SDK, CUDA Toolkit directories under windows and the name of the LIBS.

Maybe you will need to adjust the architecture m32 or m64 for 32 and 64 bits.

Hope this help.