# Compiling Cuda code in Qt Creator on Windows

Tags: c++, windows-7, qt4, cuda

I have been trying for days to get a Qt project file running on a 32-bit Windows 7 system, in which I want/need to include Cuda code. This combination of things is either so simple that no one ever bothered to put an example online, or so difficult that nobody ever succeeded, it seems. Whatever way, the only helpful forum threads I found were the same issue on Linux or Mac, or with Visual Studio on a Windows. 
All of these give all sorts of different errors, however, whether due to linking or clashing libraries, or spaces in file names or non-existing folders in the Windows version of the Cuda SDK. 
Is there someone who has a clear `.pro` file to offer that does the trick?

I am aiming to compile a simple programme with ordinary C++ code in Qt style, with Qt 4.8 libraries, which reference several Cuda modules in .cu files. Something of the form:

```
TestCUDA \
    TestCUDA.pro
    main.cpp
    test.cu
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I finally managed to assemble a `.pro` file that works on my and probably on all Windows systems. The following is an easy test programme that should probably do the trick. The following is a small project file plus test programme that works at least on my system.

The file system looks as follows:

```
TestCUDA \
    TestCUDA.pro
    main.cpp
    vectorAddition.cu
```

The project file reads:

```
TARGET = TestCUDA

# Define output directories
DESTDIR = release
OBJECTS_DIR = release/obj
CUDA_OBJECTS_DIR = release/cuda

# Source files
SOURCES += src/main.cpp

# This makes the .cu files appear in your project
OTHER_FILES +=  vectorAddition.cu

# CUDA settings <-- may change depending on your system
CUDA_SOURCES += src/cuda/vectorAddition.cu
CUDA_SDK = "C:/ProgramData/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2/C"   # Path to cuda SDK install
CUDA_DIR = "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v4.2"            # Path to cuda toolkit install
SYSTEM_NAME = Win32         # Depending on your system either 'Win32', 'x64', or 'Win64'
SYSTEM_TYPE = 32            # '32' or '64', depending on your system
CUDA_ARCH = sm_11           # Type of CUDA architecture, for example 'compute_10', 'compute_11', 'sm_10'
NVCC_OPTIONS = --use_fast_math

# include paths
INCLUDEPATH += $$CUDA_DIR/include \
               $$CUDA_SDK/common/inc/ \
               $$CUDA_SDK/../shared/inc/

# library directories
QMAKE_LIBDIR += $$CUDA_DIR/lib/$$SYSTEM_NAME \
                $$CUDA_SDK/common/lib/$$SYSTEM_NAME \
                $$CUDA_SDK/../shared/lib/$$SYSTEM_NAME
# Add the necessary libraries
LIBS += -lcuda -lcudart

# The following library conflicts with something in Cuda
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE = /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib
QMAKE_LFLAGS_DEBUG   = /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrtd.lib

# The following makes sure all path names (which often include spaces) are put between quotation marks
CUDA_INC = $$join(INCLUDEPATH,'" -I"','-I"','"')

# Configuration of the Cuda compiler
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    # Debug mode
    cuda_d.input = CUDA_SOURCES
    cuda_d.output = $$CUDA_OBJECTS_DIR/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}_cuda.o
    cuda_d.commands = $$CUDA_DIR/bin/nvcc.exe -D_DEBUG $$NVCC_OPTIONS $$CUDA_INC $$LIBS --machine $$SYSTEM_TYPE -arch=$$CUDA_ARCH -c -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT} ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}
    cuda_d.dependency_type = TYPE_C
    QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += cuda_d
}
else {
    # Release mode
    cuda.input = CUDA_SOURCES
    cuda.output = $$CUDA_OBJECTS_DIR/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}_cuda.o
    cuda.commands = $$CUDA_DIR/bin/nvcc.exe $$NVCC_OPTIONS $$CUDA_INC $$LIBS --machine $$SYSTEM_TYPE -arch=$$CUDA_ARCH -c -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT} ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}
    cuda.dependency_type = TYPE_C
    QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += cuda
}
```

Note the `QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE = /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib`: it took me a long time to figure out, but this library seems to clash with other things in Cuda, which produces strange linking warnings and errors. If someone has an explanation for this, and potentially a prettier way to get around this, I'd like to hear it.

Also, since Windows file paths often include spaces (and NVIDIA's SDK by default does so too), it is necessary to artificially add quotation marks around the include paths. Again, if someone knows a more elegant way of solving this problem, I'd be interested to know.

The `main.cpp` file looks like this:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <builtin_types.h>
#include <drvapi_error_string.h>

#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

// Forward declare the function in the .cu file
void vectorAddition(const float* a, const float* b, float* c, int n);

void printArray(const float* a, const unsigned int n) {
    QString s = "(";
    unsigned int ii;
    for (ii = 0; ii < n - 1; ++ii)
        s.append(QString::number(a[ii])).append(", ");
    s.append(QString::number(a[ii])).append(")");

    qDebug() << s;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv [])
{
    QCoreApplication(argc, argv);

    int deviceCount = 0;
    int cudaDevice = 0;
    char cudaDeviceName [100];

    unsigned int N = 50;
    float *a, *b, *c;

    cuInit(0);
    cuDeviceGetCount(&deviceCount);
    cuDeviceGet(&cudaDevice, 0);
    cuDeviceGetName(cudaDeviceName, 100, cudaDevice);
    qDebug() << "Number of devices: " << deviceCount;
    qDebug() << "Device name:" << cudaDeviceName;

    a = new float [N];    b = new float [N];    c = new float [N];
    for (unsigned int ii = 0; ii < N; ++ii) {
        a[ii] = qrand();
        b[ii] = qrand();
    }

    // This is the function call in which the kernel is called
    vectorAddition(a, b, c, N);

    qDebug() << "input a:"; printArray(a, N);
    qDebug() << "input b:"; printArray(b, N);
    qDebug() << "output c:"; printArray(c, N);

    if (a) delete a;
    if (b) delete b;
    if (c) delete c;
}
```

The Cuda file `vectorAddition.cu`, which describes a simple vector addition, look like this:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <builtin_types.h>

extern "C"
__global__ void vectorAdditionCUDA(const float* a, const float* b, float* c, int n)
{
    int ii = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (ii < n)
        c[ii] = a[ii] + b[ii];
}

void vectorAddition(const float* a, const float* b, float* c, int n) {
    float *a_cuda, *b_cuda, *c_cuda;
    unsigned int nBytes = sizeof(float) * n;
    int threadsPerBlock = 256;
    int blocksPerGrid   = (n + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;

    // allocate and copy memory into the device
    cudaMalloc((void **)& a_cuda, nBytes);
    cudaMalloc((void **)& b_cuda, nBytes);
    cudaMalloc((void **)& c_cuda, nBytes);
    cudaMemcpy(a_cuda, a, nBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(b_cuda, b, nBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    vectorAdditionCUDA<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(a_cuda, b_cuda, c_cuda, n);

    // load the answer back into the host
    cudaMemcpy(c, c_cuda, nBytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(a_cuda);
    cudaFree(b_cuda);
    cudaFree(c_cuda);
}
```

If you get this to work, then more complicated examples are self-evident, I think.

**Edit (24-1-2013):** I added the `QMAKE_LFLAGS_DEBUG   = /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrtd.lib` and the `CONFIG(debug)` with the extra `D_DEBUG` flag, such that it also compiles in debug mode.

Comment: Hi, I've almost got this working--except it's not creating `vectorAddition.obj`, I get `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'release\obj\vectorAddition.obj'`.  I note that `vectorAddition_cuda.o` is created so it's gotten past that stage, `main.obj` is created too.  Any idea how to get it (cl v. 10, from VS2010) to make `vectorAddition.obj`?

Comment: Ok figured out my issue.  You've saved me an incredible amount of time here, thanks so much.

Comment: Hi, any chance of you putting up a 64-bit version of this, i.e. the appropriately modified .pro file?  I've been trying to figure out how to adjust the paths, etc. but just can't quite put it together.

Comment: I don't have a 64-bit system so I have no way of testing it. But I think that all you need to do is to change the system folder and type to 64, and leave everything else the same. Like this:
`SYSTEM_NAME = Win32`
`SYSTEM_TYPE = 32`

Does that work?

Comment: Thanks for replying @Jelle.  Unfortunately not, I tried with `x64` and `64` respectively but that wasn't enough.  Trying different things, I get `nvcc fatal: Visual Studio configuration file '(null)' could not be found for installation` or `nvopencc WARNING: /lib does not contain all of the Open64 compiler phases` errors.  I have an x64 directory which is a subdir of v5.0/lib, and nvopencc is in a v5.0/open64 directory but I can't configure the program to see the right things. I've done a reasonable amount of googling but didn't find anything that seemed to work.

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid I can't make to much sense out of that, but admittedly I don't have much experience with compiler 64-bit programmes. I'm a bit surprised that the warning says, that it is looking for thing in `/lib`. Are you sure you changed `SYSTEM_NAME` to `x64`? If that's not it, I suggest you start a new topic on exactly that error.

Answer (score 1):

Using msvc 2010 I found that the linker does not accept the -l parameter, however nvcc needs it. Therefore I made a simple change in the .pro file:

```
# Add the necessary libraries
CUDA_LIBS = cuda cudart
# The following makes sure all path names (which often include spaces) are put between quotation marks
CUDA_INC = $$join(INCLUDEPATH,'" -I"','-I"','"')
# LIBRARIES IN FORMAT NEEDED BY NVCC
NVCC_LIBS = $$join(CUDA_LIBS,' -l','-l', '')
# LIBRARIES IN FORMAT NEEDED BY VISUAL C++ LINKER
LIBS += $$join(CUDA_LIBS,'.lib ', '', '.lib')
```

And the nvcc command (release version):

```
cuda.commands = $$CUDA_DIR/bin/nvcc.exe $$NVCC_OPTIONS $$CUDA_INC $$NVCC_LIBS --machine $$SYSTEM_TYPE -arch=$$CUDA_ARCH -c -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT} ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}
```

$$NVCC_LIBS was inserted instead of $$LIBS.
The whole .pro file, which works for me:

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = TestCUDA
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

# Define output directories
DESTDIR = release
OBJECTS_DIR = release/obj
CUDA_OBJECTS_DIR = release/cuda

# Source files
SOURCES += main.cpp

# This makes the .cu files appear in your project
OTHER_FILES +=  vectorAddition.cu

# CUDA settings <-- may change depending on your system
CUDA_SOURCES += vectorAddition.cu
#CUDA_SDK = "C:/ProgramData/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2/C"   # Path to cuda SDK install
CUDA_DIR = "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v5.0"           # Path to cuda toolkit install
SYSTEM_NAME = win32         # Depending on your system either 'Win32', 'x64', or 'Win64'
SYSTEM_TYPE = 32            # '32' or '64', depending on your system
CUDA_ARCH = sm_11           # Type of CUDA architecture, for example 'compute_10', 'compute_11', 'sm_10'
NVCC_OPTIONS = --use_fast_math

# include paths
INCLUDEPATH += $$CUDA_DIR/include
               #$$CUDA_SDK/common/inc/ \
               #$$CUDA_SDK/../shared/inc/

# library directories
QMAKE_LIBDIR += $$CUDA_DIR/lib/$$SYSTEM_NAME
                #$$CUDA_SDK/common/lib/$$SYSTEM_NAME \
                #$$CUDA_SDK/../shared/lib/$$SYSTEM_NAME


# The following library conflicts with something in Cuda
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE = /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib
QMAKE_LFLAGS_DEBUG   = /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrtd.lib

# Add the necessary libraries
CUDA_LIBS = cuda cudart
# The following makes sure all path names (which often include spaces) are put between quotation marks
CUDA_INC = $$join(INCLUDEPATH,'" -I"','-I"','"')
NVCC_LIBS = $$join(CUDA_LIBS,' -l','-l', '')
LIBS += $$join(CUDA_LIBS,'.lib ', '', '.lib')

# Configuration of the Cuda compiler
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    # Debug mode
    cuda_d.input = CUDA_SOURCES
    cuda_d.output = $$CUDA_OBJECTS_DIR/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}_cuda.o
    cuda_d.commands = $$CUDA_DIR/bin/nvcc.exe -D_DEBUG $$NVCC_OPTIONS $$CUDA_INC $$NVCC_LIBS --machine $$SYSTEM_TYPE -arch=$$CUDA_ARCH -c -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT} ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}
    cuda_d.dependency_type = TYPE_C
    QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += cuda_d
}
else {
    # Release mode
    cuda.input = CUDA_SOURCES
    cuda.output = $$CUDA_OBJECTS_DIR/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}_cuda.o
    cuda.commands = $$CUDA_DIR/bin/nvcc.exe $$NVCC_OPTIONS $$CUDA_INC $$NVCC_LIBS --machine $$SYSTEM_TYPE -arch=$$CUDA_ARCH -c -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT} ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}
    cuda.dependency_type = TYPE_C
    QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += cuda
}
```

I also added some essential declarations, i.e. QT += core for the app to work, and also removed the SDK part, which I did not find useful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this combination to work. Could not make it work due to a number of dependencies in 
my project. 
My final solution was to break the application into two separate applications on Windows
1)

1. CUDA application developed in VC and running as a service/DLL in Windows
2. GUI interface developed in QT and using the DLL for CUDA related tasks.

Hope it saves some time of others

Comment: So you mean that I cannot have a project including .cpp and .cu file? iwant .cpp file compile using gcc and cu use NVCC, and I need to all a function from cu file in .cpp