# Compiling CUDA in QT with MinGW

Tags: windows, qt, cuda, mingw, nvcc

My question is related to the thread [compiling cuda with QT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266264/compiling-cuda-code-in-qt-creator-on-windows/15588783#15588783); I followed the instruction given in the thread. Below is my error log:

```
13:41:45: Running build steps for project CUDA-QT...
13:41:45: Starting: "C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" clean
C:/QtSDK/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f Makefile.Debug clean
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory `Z:/QTProjects/CUDA-QT'
del release\cuda\vectorAddition_cuda.o
del release\cuda\vectorAddition_cuda.o debug\obj\main.o
Could Not Find Z:\QTProjects\CUDA-QT\release\cuda\vectorAddition_cuda.o
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `Z:/QTProjects/CUDA-QT'
C:/QtSDK/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f Makefile.Release clean
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory `Z:/QTProjects/CUDA-QT'
del release\cuda\vectorAddition_cuda.o
del release\cuda\vectorAddition_cuda.o release\obj\main.o
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `Z:/QTProjects/CUDA-QT'
Could Not Find Z:\QTProjects\CUDA-QT\release\cuda\vectorAddition_cuda.o
Could Not Find Z:\QTProjects\CUDA-QT\debug\obj\main.o
Could Not Find Z:\QTProjects\CUDA-QT\release\cuda\vectorAddition_cuda.o
Could Not Find Z:\QTProjects\CUDA-QT\release\cuda\vectorAddition_cuda.o
Could Not Find Z:\QTProjects\CUDA-QT\release\obj\main.o
13:41:45: The process "C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
13:41:45: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
13:41:45: Starting: "C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:/QtSDK/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory `Z:/QTProjects/CUDA-QT'
"c:\Program Files\NVIDIA\CUDA\CUDAToolkit\bin\nvcc.exe" -D_DEBUG --use_fast_math -            I"C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v5.5/include" -lC:/Program Files/NVIDIA         GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v5.5/lib/win32/cuda -lC:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing     Toolkit/CUDA/v5.5/lib/win32/cudart --machine 32 -arch=sm_11 -c -o     release\cuda\vectorAddition_cuda.o vectorAddition.cu
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `Z:/QTProjects/CUDA-QT'
nvcc : fatal error : A single input file is required for a non-link phase when an     outputfile is specified
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [release/cuda/vectorAddition_cuda.o] Error -1
mingw32-make.exe: *** [debug] Error 2
13:41:45: The process "C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building project CUDA-QT (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

I have added nvcc.exe path in my .pro file; still no success

Starting a new thread as stackoverflow does not yet allow me to post comments on the original thread.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling Cuda code in Qt Creator on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266264/compiling-cuda-code-in-qt-creator-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

CUDA support for MinGw is not available. CUDA is only supported by Visual C++ environment in Windows. Using CUDA with QT under MinGw was not an option for me after this.